# R setup attempt to use zero-length variable name error

Tags: r

Im trying to run a data set code on R but its constantly giving attempt to use zero-length variable name error.
here why setup code chunk.

````
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)```
````

Comment: Hi Fahad. It's not clear what your question is. The code you posted is an RMarkdown setup chunk which actually look like this:                                          "```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```"

Comment: Is your code inside a R script or is it part of a R Markdown document?